# How a Nested Component become render?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, nested, components, rendering

Let's create a component used in a page containing a nested component.
For example -

> **containerComponent.tsx**

```
import NestedComponent from '../components/nestedComponent';

const ContainerComponent = () => {
  const { value, setValue} = useState(0);

  return (
      <>
        <h1>This is the Nested Component</h1>
        <NestedComponent />
        <button onClick={()=>setValue(value+1)}>
          {{ value }} time Updated
        </button>
      </>
  );
};

export default ContainerComponent;
```

Here we used the Parent Component in index.tsx as below -

> **index.tsx**

```
import ContainerComponent from '../components/containerComponent';

const Home = ()=> {
  return (
      <div>
        <ContainerComponent />
      </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

> Here when i click on the button from the view of home page the "value" state variable is updated & the ContainerComponent (parent of NestedComponent) become re-render. **But is the nested component also render ?** (Though there is no parameter or props value passed through nested component from it's parent.)

Comment: Functional components always rerender children.

Comment: And you can optionally use [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to reduce unnecessary re-rendering

Comment: Why Class based component don't @DrewReese ?

Comment: Class-based components have lifecycle functions, like [shouldcomponentupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) that help it. Functional components do not have any lifecycle functions. A close analog is the `useEffect` hook that can roughly equate to `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`. If you read the link about React.memo, you'll find it is "similar to `React.PureComponent` but for function components instead of classes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi export your NestedComponent using React.memo then it will not be rendered when any state is changed in ContainerComponent. This is for Functional Component.

**Here is the code**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const NestedComponent = () => {
    const {value, setValue, errors} = useState(0);
    console.log('child');
    return (
        <div>
            ContainerComponent
        </div>
    );
};

export default React.memo(NestedComponent);
```

**For class component,** you should extends your class from React.PureComponent instead of React.Component like..

```
class NestedComponent extends React.PureComponent{
   render(){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: What for a class based component ? @Kabir

Comment: @YadabSd, for class component, you should extends your class from React.PureComponent  instead of React.Component like.. class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent